# std::vector of std::array of different sizes

Tags: c++, containers

As an exercise, I would like to construct a vector containing `std::array<unsigned char, N>` objects (where `N` varies).

My attempt was to construct a base class `GenericArray` from which a `MyArray<N>` will derive, such that the container will actually be: `std::vector<GenericArray*>`. However, since the actual array variable must reside in the derived class, I do not see a way to make use of this data from the `std:vector<GenericArray*>` itself.

Here is my full attempt, which obviously produces: `error: ‘class GenericArray’ has no member named ‘data’`

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<std::size_t N>
using arr_t = std::array<unsigned char, N>;

class GenericArray
{
public:
    ~GenericArray() = default;
};

template<std::size_t N>
class MyArray : public GenericArray
{
public:
    arr_t<N> data;

    MyArray(const arr_t<N>& data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<GenericArray*> vs;

    vs.emplace_back(new MyArray<2>({ 'a', 'b' }));
    vs.emplace_back(new MyArray<4>({ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }));

    assert(vs.size() == 2);

    for (const auto& x : vs[0]->data)
    {
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>`?

Comment: I know that "saner" alternatives exist, but this is simply an exercise (I edited the post). I want to understand the best way to proceed when this may be an actual constraint.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>` is the easiest solution to get this done.  You could also use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>>`

Comment: The code is flawed anyway.  The `GenericArray` destructor is not `virtual`.  Second, you've introduced `new` to the code, and there is no corresponding `delete`, thus memory leaks plus code that is harder to maintain.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- That's correct.. I simplified it just to reflect what I wanted to achieve, since this is just an exercise, not production code.

Comment: You seem to be mixing two concepts. If you want base class pointers in the containerr, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/rcdoef99P) would work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo -- That's exactly what I wanted to achieve, thank you! Please write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @AlexandruDinu :Ok, you're welcome, added. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be mixing two concepts. I recommend the version in eerorika's answer but if you really want base class pointers in your container, here's one way:

````
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class GenericArray {
public:
    using value_type = unsigned char;
    using iterator = value_type*;

    template<std::size_t N>
    using arr_t = std::array<value_type, N>;

    virtual ~GenericArray() = default; // must be virtual to call the derived dtor
    virtual iterator begin() = 0;      // used for iterating in the derived class
    virtual iterator end() = 0;
    // add `const` versions too as needed
};

template<std::size_t N>
class MyArray : public GenericArray {
public:
    arr_t<N> data;

    MyArray(const arr_t<N>& data) : data(data) {}
    iterator begin() override { return data.data(); }             // overridden
    iterator end() override { return data.data() + data.size(); } // -"-
};

int main() {    // no need for main(void)
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GenericArray>> vs;

    vs.emplace_back(new MyArray<2>({ 'a', 'b' }));
    vs.emplace_back(new MyArray<4>({ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }));

    // loop over the elements:
    for(auto& ptr : vs) {
        for(auto& x : *ptr) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}```
````

Comment: Thanks for showing a solution for this and thanks to others for pointing out best practices.

I know that `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>` is the best alternative here, but I really wanted to satisfy my curiosity of whether you can wrap `std::array`s in this manner.

Comment: @AlexandruDinu Curiosity to learn is always nice! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to construct a vector containing std::array<unsigned char, N> objects (where N varies).

You cannot. Vectors, like all standard containers are homogeneous. They consist of a single element type. `std::array<unsigned char, N>` and `std::array<unsigned char, M>` are different types - given that N != M, and thus they cannot be stored in a homogeneous container.

You can use `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>` instead.

Comment: Right, I assumed that wrapping the actual data under a `GenericArray *` will solve this problem.

Comment: @AlexandruDinu It's not a good solution. Vector of vectors is a better solution.

Comment: I totally understand that -- but for the sake of the argument, given this constraint, how would one approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. Let's say you make a class which contains a secvence of `std::array<char,N>`s with a `get` method. what should be the size of the returned result. The compiler must know the memory-size of all, variables for compiling, but it doesn't know the size of `auto p=vct.get(i);`
If get returns a pointer than size size of `auto p=*vct.get(i);` is undefined.

The closest you can get is returning `void*` and casting it to `array<char,N>*` but N must be known compile-time